# Customize tab menu in Opera

Tags: opera, browser-tabs

In Opera 49 top right corner of title bar, there's an additional icon for the "Tab Menu". When clicked it displays "Recently closed tabs" and "Open tabs".

**Is it possible to customize the "Tab Menu" for displaying either top sites (most visited pages), recently opened sites or a custom list of web sites entered by me?**

Note: I don't like using the bookmark bar as it permanently occupies part of the space available for the page. Currently I use start page but it's slow and overrides current page or takes an additional click for making a new tab.

**Update:** as a workaround I've installed this extension: https://addons.opera.com/en-gb/extensions/details/improve-tabs-by-clicking